# Merging output from cor.test in R dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to perform cor.test in R in a dataframe:
For a toy dataset of X and Y, I used the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
X = c(0.88,1.3,5.6,3.1)
Y = c(0,1,1,1)
ft<-cor.test(X,Y)
tidy(ft) %>% 
  select(estimate, p.value, conf.low, conf.high) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = 'grp')
```

which gives me the following result:

```
grp   estimate p.value conf.low conf.high
<chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
  1 1        0.571   0.429   -0.864     0.989
```

Now, a short version of my dataframe is like:

```
df<-structure(list(X_sample1 = c(0.11, 0.98, 0.88), X_sample2 = c(0.13, 
                                                                0, 1.3), X_sample3 = c(1.5, 3.5, 5.6), X_sample4 = c(3.2, 2.4, 
                                                                                                                     3.1), Y_sample1 = c(0L, 1L, 0L), Y_sample2 = c(0L, 0L, 1L), Y_sample3 = c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                               1L, 1L), Y_sample4 = c(1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Product1", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "Product2", "Product3"))
```

I want to perform cor.test in each row of the df between X and Y groups. Thus, in the above example df, the groups are:

```
X = c(0.11,0.13,1.5,3.2)
Y = c(0,0,1,1)
---------------
X = c(0.98,0,3.5,2.4)
Y = c(1,0,1,1)
---------------
X = c(0.88,1.3,5.6,3.1)
Y = c(0,1,1,1)
```

I want a output like:

```
grp estimate    p.value conf.low    conf.high
Product1    0.88    0.12    -0.525  0.997
Product2    0.743   0.257   -0.762  0.994
Product3    0.571   0.429   -0.864  0.989
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be:

```
df %>%
 rownames_to_column(var = "grp") %>%
 rowwise()  %>%
 transmute(grp,
           tidy(cor.test(c_across(starts_with("X")), c_across(starts_with("Y"))))) %>%
 select(grp, estimate, p.value, conf.low, conf.high) 

  grp      estimate p.value conf.low conf.high
  <chr>       <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1 Product1    0.880   0.120   -0.525     0.997
2 Product2    0.743   0.257   -0.762     0.994
3 Product3    0.571   0.429   -0.864     0.989
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am getting : could not find function "pivot_longer" - is there any package I need to load?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting this message for my post?

Comment: Yes, now I am getting: could not find function "rownames_to_column". May be I need to update the dplyr.Thank you for your help.

Comment: `rownames_to_column()` is in `tibble` library, while `pivot_longer()` is in `tidyr` library. However, I'm not using `pivot_longer()` in my post.

Comment: yes, not sure why but when I load library(tibble) your code works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr` and `broom`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
df %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  pivot_longer(-rowname, names_to = c(".value", "sample"), 
               names_sep = "_sample") %>%
  nest_by(rowname) %>%
  summarize(cors1 = tidy(cor.test(data$X, data$Y)))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   rowname [3]
  rowname cors1$estimate $statistic $p.value $parameter $conf.low $conf.high
  <chr>            <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>      <int>     <dbl>      <dbl>
1 Produc~          0.880      2.62     0.120          2    -0.525      0.997
2 Produc~          0.743      1.57     0.257          2    -0.762      0.994
3 Produc~          0.571      0.984    0.429          2    -0.864      0.989
```

Comment: thanks, I am getting :could not find function "nest_by"

Comment: `nest_by` is newer in `dplyr ` I am using v 1.0.1. There is a similar `nest` function in `tidyr`.